# Returning nested unordered list under an ordered list from the results of mapping an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to return a nested unordered list inside an ordered list.

Given this output:

```
["Input: nums = [2,2,1,1,5,3,3,5] Output: 7 Explanation: For the subarray [2,2,1,1,5,3,3] of length 7, if we remove nums[4] = 5, we will get [2,2,1,1,3,3], so that each number will appear exactly twice.","Input: nums = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5] Output: 13"]
```

I would like to return this output

Examples:

```
1. 
Input: 
nums = [2,2,1,1,5,3,3,5]

Output:
7

Explanation:
For the subarray [2,2,1,1,5,3,3] of length 7, if we remove nums[4] = 5, we will get [2,2,1,1,3,3], so that each number will appear exactly twice.

2.
Input:
nums = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5]

Output:
13
```

This is what I have tried:

```
   function formatExamples(example){
    const exampleArr = example.slice(3).split(/\S+(?=: )/g)
    exampleArr.shift()
    return exampleArr
   }
...
            <h5> Examples: </h5>
            <ol> 
                {arrExamples.map((example, idx) => {
                    <ul>
                        return {formatExamples(example).map((elem, ind) =>{
                            return(<li>{elem}</li>)
                        })}
                    </ul>
                    // return(<li key={idx}> {formatExamples(example)}</li>)
                })}
            </ol>
```

However, this returns nothing (blank)

Comment: you should write this `const exampleArr = example[0].slice(3).split(/\S+(?=: )/g)`
your string functions don't have any access to you string by just referring them to your object.

Comment: @FarbodShabani I am iterating through an array and passing each element into `formatExamples`. Why would I need to get the 0th index of a string? Because what is being passed into the function as example is a string. Also, the function itself does what I expect it to

Comment: what is arrExamples?